# Is there any option to know the status of twilio message?

Tags: c#, twilio

I am a Twilio User. How can i know the status of my message Sent. I want to know status i.e., Delivered, UnDelivered or Sent. If we provide an Url does twilio sends status to it By Sid. If there is such option where can i set it??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [REST API: Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message)

**Message Instance Resource**

This resource represents an individual SMS or MMS message.

**Resource URI**

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages/{MessageSid}
```

Then read the status property:

**Status**

> The status of this message. Either queued, sending, sent,failed,
>   delivered, undelivered, receiving or received. See detailed
>   descriptions of these statuses below.

**EDIT**

When you POST a new Message

**HTTP POST to Messages**

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages
```

You can include the following optional parameters:

```
StatusCallback
```

> A URL that Twilio will POST to each time your message status changes
>   to one of the following: failed, sent, delivered, or undelivered.
>   Twilio will POST the MessageSid along with the other standard request
>   parameters as well as MessageStatus and ErrorCode.

```
ApplicationSid
```

> Twilio will POST MessageSid as well as MessageStatus=sent or
>   MessageStatus=failed to the URL in the MessageStatusCallback property
>   of this Application. If the StatusCallback parameter above is also
>   passed, the Application's MessageStatusCallback parameter will take
>   precedence.

**StatusCallback Parameter**

> Each time a message status changes, Twilio will make an asynchronous
>   HTTP request to the StatusCallback URL, if you provided one.

```
Request Parameters
```

> The parameters Twilio passes to your application in its request to the
>   StatusCallback URL include all the standard request parameters and
>   these additional parameters:

```
MessageStatus
```

> The status of the message. Message delivery information is reflected
>   in message status. [INFO](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#sms-status-values)

```
ErrorCode
```

> The error code (if any) associated with your message. If your message
>   status is failed or undelivered, the ErrorCode can give you more
>   information about the failure. If the message was delivered
>   successfully, no ErrorCode will be present. Described [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#error-values)

Comment: I should not call any url, It just have to send me notification to url once status of message is changed from Queued to sent or delivered or undelivered

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time

Comment: What should I pass in StatusCallback url? It is returning to the url specified but with nothing info i have received MessageStatus or MessageSid.

Comment: in the StatusCallback param you should specify the URL which Twillio will POST to each time your message status changes, your url should be able to process the StatusCallback request

Comment: I have passed the url and everything is going well.. But i am unable to get parameters

Comment: Twillio doesn't post to your page/api?

Comment: Then how can i know the status of my message

Comment: twillio will post to your page/api, you should parse the twillio's request parameter 'StatusCallback' -> MessageStatus

Comment: This is the Url i am specifying http://www.example.com/Calls/CallbackURLforMsg.aspx. Is this the format twilio posts http://www.example.com/Calls/CallbackURLforMsg.aspx?MessageSid=dfkjgsdf&MessageStatus=sent

Comment: string url = "http://example.com/Calls/CallbackURLforMsg.aspx"; var message = twilio.SendMessage("+########", PhoneNumber, body, url);  Here is my coding in c#

Comment: please avoid extend discussion in comments, I suggest to edit your question, I can't understand your comments , sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67594/discussion-between-07405-and-invernomuto).

Comment: In case of failed/undelivered status in callback response, errorCode is a numeric code. How do you fetch the error message? Is there any parameter like errorDescription or something? I cannot print all the parameters because I am unable to emulate a failed test with a free account.

Comment: are you talking about https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/reference?

Comment: @Inferon yes, same can be found here too: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#error-values with a human readable description. How do you people get the errorMessage/description from errorCode. Does it come along as any of the params in the response (in case of failed/undelivered status)?

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't help you, btw I suggest you to make a new question. all the best